# Return results from mysql, using user functions

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Please tell, why this code is wrong?

```
function myres () {
   $db = new mysqli("localhost","userrr","pass","mvc");
   $res = $db->query("SELECT * FROM news ");
   return $res;
}


while ($row = myres()->fetch_row()) {
    echo  $row[0];
}
```

P.S.
this code is working:

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost","userrr","pass","mvc");
$res = $db->query("SELECT * FROM news ");
while ($row = $res->fetch_row()) {
    echo  $row[0];
}
```

Comment: Your `myres()` is executed each time the `while` condition is checked. If you extract it to a variable before the `while` loop, it will work better.

Comment: Why don't you just take the query out of the function, or have it return an array and do a `foreach`?

Comment: Thanks very much all, my error is undestood, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you call `myres()` every time, I think:

```
while ($row = myres()->fetch_row()) {
  echo  $row[0];
}
```

So every time `$row` contain first row of the result, and it will not stop. It will works fine, I think:

```
$res = myres();

while ($row = $res->fetch_row()) {
  echo  $row[0];
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer, and would be more-suitable as a comment.

Comment: This lends credence to the idea it's being called new each time: http://codepad.org/9DeSMUvu